# Get all GCP instances under project using rest API

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sdk

The below api gives instances based on a particular zone.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list

I am using java client library to connect with GCP.

It is possible using gcloud according to this link
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/list

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To list all instances in all regions and zones for a project, use the `aggregatedList` method.

[Method: instances.aggregatedList](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/aggregatedList)